# want some space between text and button

Tags: html, css

below is the code, i had a one image, below that image there is Price and a button, i want some space between price and button which should be left and right to the image

```css
.new {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #66C4C4;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
.wrapper {
                text-align: center;
            }

.show{
                background-color: #2D318A;
                color: white;
                padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
                border-radius: 3px;
                text-decoration: none;
               float: right;
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="new">New Released</a>
        </div> 
        <img src="https://www.google.com.np/search?q=django+imagefield&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHk57k89fcAhUJVH0KHbxAC08Q_AUICygC&biw=1396&bih=690#imgrc=3ukNSrarUo82hM:" style="width: 300px" height="200px">
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Price: Rs 14000
                                  
                </td>
                <td> <a href="#" class="show">Join Now</a></td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
```

Comment: you can replace the html table, which is not needed there, with two divs. The two divs can be displayed inline-block, and one div floated to the left, and the other one to the right.

Comment: You can always go with relative positioning:
position: relative;
top: -8px;

Comment: You mean like `<price> <image> <button>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this approach it will work fine. Best part is you can even adjust its responsiveness with classes. Don't need to use table for such things. That's considered bad code.

You was missing closing bracket of .new class.

```css
    .new {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #66C4C4;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  }
  .image-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .image-container img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .image-container span {
    float: left;
  }
  .show {
    float: right;
    background-color: #2D318A;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="new">New Released</a>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http://site8.dealerbase.co.nz/media/1707/300x200.gif" />
  <br>
  <span>Price: Rs 14000</span>
  <a href="#" class="show">Join Now</a></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item-wrap{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.item-footer{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-wrap">
  <div class='item-img'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=0'>
    </div>
  <div class='item-footer'>
    <div class='price'><p>Price: Rs 14000</p></div>
    <div class='item-join'>
      <p>Join Now</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**HTML:**
<tr>
    <td>
        Price: Rs 14000                      
    </td>
    <td class="joinButtonAlign"> <a href="#" class="show">Join Now</a></td>
</tr>


**CSS**

.joinButtonAlign{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left:30px;
}
```